# java 9 modules with gradle not working: error: module not found: <module name>

Tags: java, maven, gradle, java-platform-module-system

I made a minimalist java gradle project to test java 9 modules.

I made only 1 module and tried testing depending on a third party module. But I keep getting the error when I try to build or run the project:

`module not found: commons.validator`

here are my files:

**Demo.java"**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("abcd");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**module-info.java:**

```
module auth.server.main {
    requires commons.validator;
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // for email validation
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'
}

/*this is to let gradle infer the locations of the modules*/
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}
```

Whats wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: Given both the Apache change in `groupId` convention and the existence of Bean Validation, I'd be astonished if `commons-validator:1.7` were new enough to declare modules. What's your reason for expecting `commons.validator` to exist?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- commons.validator is the automatic name given to the module, you can find it by the command `jar --file=<filepath> --describe-module` and then applying the naming rule to extract the module name
The library works well but when I define module-info in my project it stops working, same is happening with lombok as well, the ide (intellij idea ultimate) does not find it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might easy way.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.javamodularity.moduleplugin" version "1.1.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'
}
```

Check it out : https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin

Comment: It worked, but only after I created a new project and copied the old files into it, I don't know why but at least it worked. Getting gradle to work with modules let alone java module system is a hell of a task.